# android:layout_gravity="bottom" isn't working

Tags: xml, android-studio

I want to use only `LinearLayout` and want to place "RESET" button in bottom center. But it isn't going to bottom even after using `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`.

I know using `RelativeLayout` will solve the problem, but I want `LinearLayout` to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`enter code here`
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
 tools:context="com.example.android.freestylewrestlingscorekeeperapp.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Player A"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="48sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 5 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 4 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 3 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 2 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 1 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <view
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Player B"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="48dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 5 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 4 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 3 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 2 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ 1 points"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:text="RESET" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Currently the "Reset" button places just below the two teams and is in center. I want it to be in *bottom* and in *center*.

Please refer to the link for how is it showing currently.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just add a parent layout to the button. I have added `LinearLayout` and assign `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Below is the code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RESET" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for your help.It worked perfectly. But I tried to modify it a  little. I tried to use android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" inside Button instead of using android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" in LinearLayout. It shifted the button to bottom but center_horizontal isn't working. Why is it so?

Comment: @VardeepNain The reason is that because you've assigned `LinearLayout` to align each child vertically, which means that it only lets you specify the horizontal alignment of each child in the `layout_gravity` parameter. `android:android:layout_gravity="bottom"` would work in case of horizontal alignment. To make `android:android:layout_gravity="bottom"` work you have to add `layout_weight="1"` to its parent layout and add `android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

Your parent linear layout is having `vertical` orientation which means it already specifies its child layout vertically so the values `top` and `bottom` for `layout_gravity` won't work. You can use this value only when you are having your parent linear layout as `horizontal`.

As you don't want to use relative layout your option will be to `match_parent` your first linear layout and set its `layout_weight` to `1`. and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` for the button.